# prism 6 nested regions navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, prism

I have a region within a region. Main region (which holds all the others) is named **ContentRegion** and the other one which I used to display partial info is named **SettingsRegion**.

Under my bootstrapper I have defined the following:

```
        Prism.Regions.IRegionManager contentRegion = Container.TryResolve<Prism.Regions.IRegionManager>();

        #region Register Multiple Regions
        //contentRegion.RegisterViewWithRegion("ContentRegion", typeof(MainWindow));
        contentRegion.RegisterViewWithRegion("SettingsRegion", typeof(SettingsView_MainPage));


        #endregion
```

I can navigate from my ContentRegion to SettingsRegion without a problem like following:

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", Experiences.Navigation.SettingsView_MainPage.ToString());

_regionManager.RequestNavigate("SettingsRegion", Experiences.NavigationSettings.SettingsView_ShiftSettings.ToString());
```

Everything renders great, I can see both views (contents) at the same time. However when I try to navigate back to main page like following

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", Experiences.Navigation.MainPage.ToString());
```

It gives me the following error:
`{"Region with the given name is already registered: SettingsRegion"}`

I have read multiple articles regarding nested Regions, however I could not implement none. I should probably also mention that I am using Unity as well.

I am also attaching pictures so that my explanation is less confusing.

**Main View / Main Window**
[image]

**Second view where I want to show some detail under the nested region**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

So in the end I had to do the following adjustments:

remove completely the following line from Bootstrapper (I don't understand why I don't need to register it).

```
contentRegion.RegisterViewWithRegion("SettingsRegion", typeof(SettingsView_MainPage));
```

Afterwards had to do slight change under my SecondPageViewModel; originally I was directly navigating to sub page under the constructor, but once I implemented `INavigationAware` and moved the navigation to `OnNavigatedTo` then it suddenly started working.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: `RegisterViewWithRegion()` is used for _view discovery_ whereas you are using _navigation_. Two different approaches.